# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/transactions] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I thought this is a standard configuration. But I get a 404 back. Where else should I configure Spring Boot ?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TransactionStatisticsController {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionStatisticsController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/transactions",
                    method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity sendTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction request) {
        logger.info( request.toString());
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

This is my test.

```
@JsonTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TransactionStatisticsRestTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<Transaction> json;

    private static Transaction transaction;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createTransaction(){
        BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(12.3343);
        transaction = new Transaction(amount.toString(),
                                      "2010-10-02T12:23:23Z");
    }

    @Test
    public void getTransactionStatus() throws Exception {

        final String transactionJson = json.write(transaction).getJson();
        mockMvc
                .perform(post("/api/transactions")
                .content(transactionJson)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    public static byte[] convertObjectToJsonBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(transaction);
    }
}
```

Request being made is

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/transactions
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
             Body = {"amount":"12.3343000000000007077005648170597851276397705078125","timestamp":"2010-10-02T12:23:23Z[UTC]"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

> Update : I added a component scan pointing to a base package. I don't see that error now. Please see the comments where there is an answer.

Comment: have you bind @componentscan("basepackage Name")...?

Comment: I added a component scan pointing to a base package. It seems to have fixed it. Let me check the test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment section ,there was only requirement was to bind a component scan base package location .

> @Component scan -->Configures component scanning directives for use with @Configuration classes. Provides support parallel with Spring XML's  element.
>   Either basePackageClasses() or basePackages() (or its alias value()) may be specified to define specific packages to scan. If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems using `@JsonTest` does not even allow to load Application Context, results mapping is not loaded and its throw 404 so `@JsonTest` is not a replacement for `@SpringBootTest`, it is a way to easily test `json serialization/de-serialization`.

As per documentation:

> you can use the @JsonTest annotation. @JsonTest auto-configures the
>   available supported JSON mapper, which can be one of the following
>   libraries:
>
> 1. Jackson ObjectMapper, any @JsonComponent beans and any Jackson Modules
> 2. Gson
> 3. Jsonb

If by using Gson and removing `@JsonTest` your test run fine..(add Gson Dependency in pom)

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DemoKj01ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private static Transaction transaction;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createTransaction(){
        BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(12.3343);
        transaction = new Transaction(amount.toString(),
                "2010-10-02T12:23:23Z");
    }

    @Test
    public void getTransactionStatus() throws Exception {

        //final String transactionJson = json.write(transaction).getJson();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonRequest = gson.toJson(transaction);
        mockMvc
                .perform(post("/api/transactions")
                        .content(jsonRequest)
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share your project folder architecture. It might be possible that your controller package is out of the main class package. That's why it is showing 404.

This code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TransactionStatisticsController {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionStatisticsController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/transactions",
                    method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity sendTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction request) {
        logger.info( request.toString());
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

This should be into your main package where

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

this main class resides.

I hope, this will help.

Answer (score -1):

It is beacause of the trailing slas in `@RequestMapping(value = "/transactions/", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Remove it and it will be ok : `value = "/transactions/"` => `value = "/transactions"`

Comment: Not really. That doesn't change anything.I edited the code in the question now.